# Replacing entire MongoDB document with FireDAC and Delphi

Tags: mongodb, delphi, firedac

I have found demos that updates field of a document. I havent found any code that shows how to update/replace a complete document on MongoDB using FIREDAC and Delphi.

I'm looking to update/replace all the document contents.So far what I'm doing is to delete and then insert the document.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance,

Omar Z.

Comment: Have you checked this sample code from Embarcadero?https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FireDAC.MongoDB_Explore_Sample